# Return absolute path from RouteBase.GetVirtualPath

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public class CustomRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        var virtual_path_data = new VirtualPathData( this, "http://example.com" );

        return virtual_path_data;
    }
}
```

ASP.NET automatically seems to add a leading slash to any (absolute) path returned from VirtualPathData, returning in this example `/http://example.com`.

Question:

- Is it possible to generate absolute urls through the RouteBase system?
- If not: what would be the least ugly hack, so it works with `Url.Action`, `RedirectToAction` and other use cases that I'm not aware.

**Background**

I've written a routing engine based on XML, that supports mutliple domain names. So when I generate a URL only available at the other domain, I'd like to generate an absolute URL, including the domain name.

```
<host name="exm.com" controller="ShortUrl">
    <parameter name="code" action="Redirect" />
</host>  

<host name="*" default="example.com" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <x name="demo" controller="Home" action="Demo" />
    <x name="comments" controller="Comment" action="List">
        <x name="write" action="Write" />
        <x name="delete" action="Delete" />
    <x>
</host>
```

Resulting in combinations like:

`Url.Action("Demo", "Home")`

*http://example.com/demo*

`Url.Action("Write", "Comment")`

*http://example.com/comments/write*

`Url.Action("Redirect", "ShortUrl", new { code = "gH8x" } )`

*http://exm.cm/gH8x*

Note that both example.com and exm.com are referring to the same application IP, and are routed within the app.

Comment: how do you know on which Domain Url.Action or RedirectToAction should refer? The Actions always refer to UrlMappings in the current Project.

Comment: I've added more details

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Hi John, I've added an answer below. It's quite an ugly hack, but maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've made a relative ugly hack where I prefix with a special character, to determine if it should be an absolute URL.

```
public static string HostAction(this UrlHelper url, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null, bool forceOrigin = false)
{
    var route_value_dictionary = CloneRouteValues( routeValues );

    // this is being used in the routing to determine
    // if they need to route for an absolute URL
    route_value_dictionary.Add( "routeWithHostName", true );

    // if forceOrigin is false, then the Routing will not return 
    // an absolute path if it's not necessary (url relative to the current domain)
    route_value_dictionary.Add("forceOrigin", forceOrigin );

    var path = url.Action( actionName, controllerName, route_value_dictionary );

    if ( path.Length < 2 )
        return path;

    // starts with /$ ? then this is an absolute URL. Strip the first two characters
    if ( path[1] == '$' )
        return path.Substring( 2 );
    else
        return path;
}
```

Absolutetly not ideal, but until now I seem to get away with it without too much stuff breaking all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post of someone that seems to have instructions for exactly what you're trying to do. [MVC Domain Routing](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've come that article before, but as far as I understand they create the absolute path by using a separate extension method, that you explicitly need to call when you want to refer to a subdomain. I'm looking for a solution that works with all the current implementations, like vanilla Url.Action() and RedirectToAction().